# Failure in prototypical inheritance-javascript

Tags: javascript

I define two object as follow Department and Footnote

[image]

[image]

As the two object share the same method of `getData`
I would like to inherit the Department's `getData` method to Footnote by the following:

```
Footnote.prototype.getData = Department.prototype.getData;
```

Then when I create an object of footnote and call the getData method,

```
var footnote = new Footnote();
```

an error came out : Uncaught TypeError: footnote.getData is not a function

Does anyone know why and how to extend Department's getData method to Footnote

Comment: You've forgotten to add the object definitions.

Comment: @Teemu ,I have included the object definition as image

Comment: Please don't add code as an image, just copy-paste it, and format as code (select the code and click `{}` icon on the editor). What comes to the error, `getData` is an own property of the created instances, it's not in the prototype of `Department` function, it's defined in the function body. You've to pull the method out of the `Department` function, and do `Department.prototype = function getData () {...};`, then you can assign it to Footnote.prototype as you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, the `getData` method is added to a Department instance inside the Department constructor:

```
this.getData = function(){ /* ... */ }
```

You’re trying to use `Department.prototype.getData` later in the code. But this is not a function, because you haven’t assigned it. To make it work, you need to assign the getData method like this instead:

```
Department.prototype.getData = function(){ /* ... */ }
```

This will add the method to all Department instances, and it will work to assign it to the Footnote prototype too.